# Working with classes and cant get my output to work

Tags: c++, class, syntax-error, output

I'm finishing a project with a class and will have to have it output my information. I keep getting an error with line 33 saying 'Human : undeclared identifier'.

Here is my full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int height;
    int weight;
    int age;
    string name;

    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cin.clear();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter your height (in inches): ";
    cin >> height;
    cin.clear();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter your weight (in whole pounds): ";
    cin >> weight;
    cin.clear();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter your age (in whole years): ";
    cin >> age;
    cin.clear();
    cout << endl;

    Human myHuman;
    myHuman.editHeight(height);
    myHuman.editAge(age);
    myHuman.editWeight(weight);
    myHuman.editName(name);

    cout << "Your description: ";
    cout << endl;
    myHuman.outputDescription();

    return 0;
}
class Human
{
public:
    Human();
    int getAge();
    void editAge(int a);
    int getHeight();
    void editHeight(int h);
    int getWeight();
    void editWeight(int w);
    string getName();
    void editName(string in);

    void outputDescription();

private:
    int m_age;
    int m_height;
    int m_weight;
    string m_name;
};
string Human::getName()
{
    return m_name;
}
void Human::editName(string in)
{
    m_name = in;
}
int Human::getAge()
{
    return m_age;
}
void Human::editAge(int a)
{
    m_age = a;
}
int Human::getHeight()
{
    return m_height;
}
void Human::editHeight(int h)
{
    m_height = h;
}
int Human::getWeight()
{
    return m_weight;
}
void Human::editWeight(int w)
{
    m_weight = w;
}
void Human::outputDescription()
{
    cout << "Hello " << m_name << " you are " << m_height << " inches tall and weigh " << m_weight
         << " pounds, and are currently " << m_age << " years old.";
}
```

If anyone could shine some light on this for me, that would be great. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You need to declare Human class before use it. Put `class Human;` before your main. Next time show us a minimal example of your error.

Comment: You get such error, because identifier `Human` is, indeed, undeclared, when compiler gets to the statement `Human myHuman;`.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel I did that, thank you. That was a simple operator error... but after doing so, I was given this error code...

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel

Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Human::Human(void)" (??0Human@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop\C++\Stewart_THExam3\Stewart_THExam3\Stewart_THExam3.obj Stewart_THExam3

Comment: Your forget to implement tour default constructor. `Human();` is not valid, use `Human() = default;` at least.